# How to trace back #pragma pack?

Tags: ios, preprocessor, memory-alignment

I've been wrestling with an issue in iOS causing improper allocation, getting less memory back from malloc than I should have for a CPP object.   I recently discovered it was due to two translation units including the same header, one of which along its include chain had a few occurrences of `#pragma pack`.

Now, I'm not sure how to properly trace back to whichever file is using it and ensure that it fixes it.  I've added a bunch of `#pragma pack(show)` and have nailed down the offending file from the top (the offending file being the file that causes others files to have the same pack setting of 1).  I've opened that file in Xcode and run preprocess on it.

In most cases, it looks like code is setting pack back to default (8 on arm64).  Are there any tools that can help verify which is the offender along the chain?

The only tip that I have (a case of a pack 1, which is what the pack was being set to), is a header from the iOS SDK.  But even it looks to be ok.

```
# 54 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/kauth.h" 2 3 4


#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct {
 u_int8_t sid_kind;
 u_int8_t sid_authcount;
 u_int8_t sid_authority[6];

 u_int32_t sid_authorities[16];
} ntsid_t;
#pragma pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, when searching through the preprocessed source file, I wasn't able to find any instance of `#pragma pack` that wasn't undoing its setting shortly after.  However, I wasn't aware that there was another way to set packing, via `#pragma options align=(packed|reset)`.  It turns out that it wasn't being undone, but I was looking for `#pragma pack`.